# Angular: How to get submitted status of the FormGroup though dependency injection

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-reactive-forms

I would like to have access to the submitted status of a FormGroup from any child FormControl through dependency injection. I've tried injecting the NgForm directive but it throws "no provider for..." error.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found that we can inject [FormGroupDirective](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroupDirective) that contains the 'submitted' property "because this directive always lives at the top level of a form...".

```
constructor(
  private _formGroupDirective:FormGroupDirective,
) {}

get showErrorMessage():boolean {    
  return this.formControl.invalid && this._formGroupDirective?.submitted;
}
```